# Valor de Data 0000-00-00 não pode ser usado em java Date

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, data, jdbc

Antes de tudo sim, eu já adiocionei `?zeroDateTimeBehavi‌​or=convertToNull`na URL de conexão o problema é que na consulta a data zerada não vem nula e sempre solta a seguinte Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date
```

Já debuguei e sempre para na mesma data zerada sendo chamada pelo ResultSet

```
regC100.setDtDoc(resultSet.getDate(14));
```

Comment: Não é uma data válida mesmo. Por que você não grava NULL nestes casos?

Comment: A menor data possivel na API de datas java do pacote java.util ou java.sql é 01/01/1970. Logo, esta data é inexistente para a api.

Comment: Porque as queries(iinserts) são gerados dinamicamente então fazer esse tratamento seria bastante complicado

Answer (score 1):

Os outros campos foram omitidos porém consegui obter todos chamando-os individualmente com o `ALIAS`a maneira que consegui resolver foi assim:

```
SELECT if(DT_DOC='0000-00-00',NULL,DT_DOC) as DT_DOC FROM reg_c100;
```

Answer (score 0):

No MySql `0000-00-00` é considerado uma data válida, mas não pode ser representada como `java.sql.Date`.

Você pode usar uma consulta que retorna `NULL` no caso de data `0000-00-00`, ou o valor real caso contrário:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN `data`!='0000-00-00' THEN `data` END date
FROM
  suaTabela
```

Comment: Vou fazer um teste aqui

Comment: fiz um teste usando sua querie de exemplo e ficou assim: `SELECT c100.*,CASE WHEN `DT_DOC`='0000-00-00' THEN `DT_DOC`=null END date FROM `reg_c100` as c100` porém as datas retornadas não estão nulas pode me dizer o que está errado? desde já agradeço.

Comment: Tente o seguinte:

`SELECT CASE WHEN DT_DOC != '0000-00-00' THEN DT_DOC END NULL FROM reg_c100`

Comment: Basicamente vc seleciona apenas a data, porém se ela for diferente do padrão `0000-00-00` ele retorna a própria data `valida`caso contrario ele irá retornar `null` ai dependendo de seu problema vc pode adicionar o Where para outros filtros

Comment: Não consegui rodar a sua query por algum motivo o phpmyadmin mostrou um erro de sintaxe, acredito que tenha sido na parte do `NULL`, mas consegui resolver o erro vou mostrar a reposta correta, mas a sua ajudou

Comment: `CASE` não é `IF`, é mais como um operador ternário `?:`. Portanto, não pode dizer `THEN DT_DOC = NULL`, tem que dizer `THEN NULL ELSE DT_DOC`. Essencialmente o `CASE` funciona assim: `CASE WHEN [teste1] THEN [valor1] WHEN [teste2] THEN [valor2] .... ELSE [valorn] END`; o SQL tenta `[teste1]`, `[teste2]`, etc. em ordem e retorna o `[valori]` correspondente ao primeiro `[testei]` que dá verdadeiro.